# Does not contain a definition or extension method- WHEN IT DOES

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, compiler-errors

I've added services into my MVC/EF project to act as a layer between my controller and repositories.

I'm having trouble copying a method from the repo to the service. I'm trying to use `Count()` in the service but keep receiving error `does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type .. could be found`

I've implemented it exactly the same way as the repository has so I don't know why it's failing

Repositories:

```
public abstract class Repository<CEntity, TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
                                                                    where CEntity : DbContext, new()
{
    private CEntity entities = new CEntity();
    protected CEntity context
    {
        get { return entities; }
        set { entities = value; }
    }

    public virtual int Count 
    {
        get { return entities.Set<TEntity>().Count(); }
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> All()
    {
        return entities.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    }
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    int Count { get; }
    IQueryable<TEntity> All();
}
```

Service:

```
public class CampaignService : ICampaignService 
{
    private readonly IRepository<Campaign> _campaignRepository;

    public CampaignService(IRepository<Campaign> campaignRepository)
    {
        _campaignRepository = campaignRepository;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _campaignRepository.Count()**; }
    }

    public IQueryable GetAll()
    {
        return _campaignRepository.All();
    }
}

public interface ICampaignService
{
    int Count{ get; }
    IQueryable GetAll();
}
```

** it fails on this line.

`Error  4   'MarketingSystem.Repositories.Common.IRepository' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'MarketingSystem.Repositories.Common.IRepository' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The `GetAll()`/`All()` methods work fine, but `Count()` doesn't.

Can anyone spot and explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Try change `get { return _campaignRepository.Count()**; }` for `get { return GetAll().Count(); }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call `Count()` on repository. Your repository is neither `IQueryable<T>` nor `IEnumerable<T>`, so extension method `Count()` is not available to you. Actually your repository implements only `IRepository<TEntity>` Which has only three members available - `Dispose()`, `Count` and `All()`. I think you need to call `Count` property from this interface.

```
get { return _campaignRepository.Count; }
```

NOTE - `Count` is not a method - its a property.

Comment: But the `GetAll()` method works fine and returns a queryable selection of Campaigns.. Before, I called `_campaignRepository.Count()` in the controller and that worked fine too. But the service doesn't seem to like it

Comment: @JakkyD you probable called `_campaignRepository.All().Count()` - thus `All()` returns `IQueryable<T>` then linq extension method `Count()` becomes available

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I was treating Count like a method when in fact I made it a property which I completely overlooked!

Comment: @JakkyD it happens often, because usually you want to know count of items in some collection/sequence and here goes `Count()` extension method - its easy to mess with them :)

Answer (score 1):

remove `()`

```
public int Count
{
    get { return _campaignRepository.Count; }
}
```

Count is a property in Repository but you are accessing it as a method